# Can't get image from storage with file_get_contents() (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, gd

Today I've encountered a problem, probably a silly one. Basically I want to merge generated qr code image and my selected template image into one using GD library. This is my code:

```
for ($i=1; $i <= $data['table_count']; $i++) { 
            $qrImage = QrCode::format('png')
                 ->size(200)
                 ->generate('http://192.168.8.103:8000/detectagent?table='.$i.'');
            $output_file = 'qr_images/img-' . Str::random() . '.png';

            $qrImageString = imagecreatefromstring($qrImage);
            $templateImage = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents(storage_path('img/lankstinukas%20mvp3.png'))); 
            // fails here

            dd($templateImage);
            list($width, $height) = getimagesize($qrImage);

            imagecopymerge($qrImage, $templateImage, 100, 100, 50, 50, $width, $height, 100);

            imagepng($qrImage, 'merged.png');
        }
```

I have my template images in `storage/img` folder, but when I try to access it with php function `file_get_contents` I get error saying: "failed to open stream no such file or directory". However for example if I try entering that path url into browser I get my desired image, but for some reason this php function can't find it. I also tried not using `storage_path` but instead entering manually like

```
$templateImage = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($data['selected_design']));
```

where `$data['selected_design'] = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/img/lankstinukas%20mvp3.png"` But then page loads for a long time and I get `Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded`. To clear things out I have link between public and storage so that's not the case. Thank you in advance!